# Why is node.js SHA1 body different crom GitHub webhook SHA1 value?

Tags: node.js, github, sha1

I have tried many times to use node.js `crypto` package to figure `req.body` SHA1 value. But there were always different.

I am using the following code:

```
var body = req.body;
var sig = 'sha1=' + crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret).update(JSON.stringify(body)).digest('hex');
console.log(sig === req.headers['x-hub-signature']) // not equal :(
```

or

```
var body = req.body;
var sig = 'sha1=' + crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret).update(new Buffer(JSON.stringify(body))).digest('hex');  
console.log(sig === req.headers['x-hub-signature']) //not equal :(
```

I'd appreciate any help you could give me!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, I know the reason that cause this problem.
Because, Github post a string to my server and Github figure this string SHA1 value. But with my nodejs code, i use `body-parser` package as a middleware, so i got

```
{  
  payload: {...}  
}
```

and the SHA1 that, so, there were never equal.

now, we know the reason, we can solve this. just

```
  var bufferArr = [];
  var bufferLen = 0;
  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    bufferArr.push(chunk);
    bufferLen += chunk.length;
  });
  req.on('end', function() {
    var data = Buffer.concat(bufferArr, bufferLen).toString();
    var sig = 'sha1=' + crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret)
        .update(data).digest('hex');
    console.log(sig === req.headers['x-hub-signature']) // true
  }
```

I hope my experience can help others